# What are the possible ways to transfer a file of more than 100MB generated via shell script, to any URL or server?

Tags: excel, shell, curl, compression, dropbox

I have a shell script written, which generates an excel file of more than 100MB. Now, I want to transfer the file or say upload the file to one URL which is online storage server. This server will generate a URL containing the file after uploading.

The question is if we are able to upload the file using "cURL" to any given URL, then how to get the generated URL from that web page??

The URL generated after uploading the file is dynamic. (Dropbox kind of storage)
If it is not possible to get that URL then how to transfer such a big file.

Note: It is kind of automation, so please answer keeping automation in mind.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21394709/2836621 might help

Comment: but how do I get the URL where the file is uploaded??
does that mean $file contains the URL??

Comment: By the way, Thank you very much for answer. :)